# Is there any way to know which version of custom tab app user is using in teams?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-teams-js

We have a custom tab app installed in teams. Recently we've updated the manifest file where we've put the version as 2.1.0. Now my question is if there are any ways to know which version of the app the user is using(are they using the latest version or the old version.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have Graph API to [List apps installed for user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-list-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-the-names-and-other-details-of-apps-installed-for-the-user) and [Get installed app for user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/userteamwork-get-installedapps?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-get-the-names-and-other-details-of-the-app-installed-for-the-user).

Use below Graph API to Get the names and other details of apps installed for the user. It includes the version as well.

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id | user-principal-name}/teamwork/installedApps?$expand=teamsAppDefinition
```

Use below Graph API to Get the name and other details of the app installed for the user

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user-id | user-principal-name}/teamwork/installedApps/{app-installation-id}=?$expand=teamsAppDefinition
```